# How do I restrict content based on whether a user is logged in or not?

Tags: php, html, authentication, video-streaming

So basically, I'm trying to build a website for online learning and I need to post videos to the website that can only be viewed if the person is a subscribed member. A few videos or a part of the video should be viewable as a demo but the rest should have the viewer to be a member.

Comment: How do you record the fact a user has logged in?

Comment: I think a good place to start is to do some discovery within a demo repository which already has a simple workflow for authentication and authorization.  These are a couple examples: https://github.com/bezkoder/mean-stack-authentication-authorization, https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-fullstack-authentication-system-with-react-express-mongodb-heroku-and-netlify/, https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/01/react-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not check for that permission wherever you need it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how you build a secure login for a web based application then the usual approach is to use sessions and cookies.

There are many examples depending on the javascript framework or application you are using and many good guides online.

The approach is essentially:

- user logs in to your web site sending username and password securely over HTTPS
- you verify the login and generate a session id which you send securely to the browser and the browser stores the session id in a coookie
- Further requests, until the session id times out, include the session id in the secure messaging from the browser to the server.

Some implementations may also check the 'fingerprint' of the browser sending the session id to make sure it is coming from the correct browser - i.e. that someone did not copy the session id and use it from another browser.

If you want to stop your video being copied by registered logged in users, then you can't really do this as there is always a way to copy videos streamed. The usual approach is to encrypt the video and either share the keys manually or via one of the usual DRM systems, the most common ones being Widevine, PlayReady and FairPlay.